# How do I uninstall Master PDF Editor 3?

Tags: software-uninstall, master-pdf-editor

How do I **uninstall** Master PDF Editor 3? Have already tried the package manager, it shows only the "reinstall" option!

Comment: Can't be, if you have a reinstall option, than you have a remove option also.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see the package in your package manager, you should run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get remove master-pdf-editor
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get purge master-pdf-editor3
```

Comment: uninstalling he asked?

Comment: Although it might be obvious, adding a little explanation to your answer would be helpful. Maybe explain what `sudo apt-get purge` does exactly.

Answer (score 1):

First search for the application name then remove it after:

```
apt-cache search master-pdf
sudo apt-get remove -purge master-pdf-editor
```

[image: master-pdf-terminal-remove]